# RelativeLayout внутри CollectionView. Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, коллекции, xamarin.forms, android-relativelayout

Использую Xamarin.Forms. В `CollectionView` находятся картинки.

Я хочу, чтобы `CollectionView` за раз отображал только 5 элементов на экранах любого размера.

```xml
<Grid x:Name="grd" HeightRequest="50" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="46"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="46"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        <CollectionView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="clv" ItemsSource="{Binding ImagesArray}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" SnapPointsAlignment="Start" SnapPointsType="Mandatory" ItemSpacing="0"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RelativeLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageName}" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.2}"
                           RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.2}"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
</Grid>
```

Пробовал менять Factor на 0.2, чтобы размер картинки соответствовал 1\5 от колонки грида, в которой `CollectionView` находится, но он уменьшает изображение до очень маленьких размеров. Хотя на разных экранах и правда показывает 5 изображений только.

Есть ли возможность отобразить только 5 элементов из коллекции другим способом?

Comment: Может MaxWidth и MaxHeight надо ограничивать? Если у вас только ровно 5 элементов, быть может UniformGrid поможет? Ей можно задавать количество колонок и строк https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/uniformgrid Попробуйте ее как ItemsPanel подключить.

Comment: покурю, спасибо

Comment: Но вообще в коллекции не 5 элементов. Их количество всего разное, но строго от 5 штук. Пытаюсь добиться того, чтобы одновременно на экране могло находиться только 5 картинок. Тут главное, чтобы на экранах другого размера все выглядело одинаково. Поэтому и решил relative использовать.